# Detect specific return type of C# function python.net

Tags: python, c#, python-3.x, python.net

Let's say I have the following C# function

```
public byte AddOne(byte r){

    return r + 1
}
```

In my python code, I am able to call the function by doing something like

```
x = AddOne(3)
```

When I check the type of x, it always returns an int. This is true even if I change my C# function to return a long, a short, or an int. I want x to be a numpy.int8 if a byte is returned, or numpy.int64 if long is returned. How can I go about doing this since currently an int is always returned?

Answer (score 0):

In Python.NET 2.5+ you can define [custom codecs](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/wiki/Codecs:-customizing-object-marshalling-between-.NET-and-Python). In 2.5 they can not be used to override primitive type conversion, however, on the C# side you can define custom types corresponding to `numpy.int64`, `numpy.int8`, etc, then register codecs for them.

```
public struct I8 {
  public byte Value;

  static I8() {
    var i8 = Py.Import("numpy").GetAttr("int8");
    PyObjectConversions.RegisterEncoder(new I8Codec(i8));
  }
}

public class I8Codec: IPyObjectEncoder {
  readonly PyObject i8;
  public I8Codec(PyObject i8) => this.i8 = i8;

  public PyObject TryEncode(object value)
    // call numpy.int8 constructor
    => i8.Invoke(((I8)value).Value.ToPython());

  public PyObject CanEncode(Type type) => type == typeof(I8);
}

I8 DoubleIt(byte val) => new I8 { Value = val*2 };
```

Alternatively, you can modify [this line](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/blob/7a9dcfa162f038fc599988ca59eb49a84be0affc/src/runtime/converter.cs#L152) to allow codecs on primitive types, and implement `I8Codec` for `byte`. However, trying to do it for `int` might cause unintended consequences. E.g. `ICollection.Count` will start returning `numpy.int32`, which you probably don't want.

Comment: Thank you! Would I just put this I8Codec class in my file where I have my C# function defined? I'm a little unsure on how to use this class.

Comment: @WirableWhisper7 I do not know the structure of your projects. Personally, I'd have a separate C# library with `I8` and `I8Codec` in case I'd need to reuse them. But just putting them both next to the class implementing your `AddOne` should be fine. I will also update the sample a bit to make it easily usable from Python.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, you'd recommend adding that code into a separate file and referencing that dll in python.net? Would I just be importing the I8Codec class? I'm also curious about what the python code to leverage and use this class would look like.